# Sending multiple response with API.ai

Tags: chatbot, api-ai

I want to send 2 separate text responses from my intent.

The user says
"what's your name?"

The bot responds
"David"
"But my friends call me Dave"

In the api.ai docs it tells me to add multiple Text Responses to split up my response, and to add multiple phrases to a single Text Response to get a random answer.

When using the test console all works as expected.

But when I try this with Slack or Web Integrations I just get one phrase from one Text Response.

Is this a problem with Slack and Web, or am I doing something wrong?  There is no webhook servers connected.

Comment: Its working for me: intent screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/OIeCimM.png Working in slack screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/TIjA8AS.png are you expecting something different from the screenshots or are you not getting the same results as my screenshot?

Comment: I am noticing this same issue and have used API.ai many times before without this- it 'appears' to be a potential bug or update they have made without updating the documentation.

Comment: Matt or macasas can you respond to my comment?  It seems to be working for me, are you both doing something different than I am (see my screenshot on how my intent is setup: i.imgur.com/OIeCimM.png)?  or are you setting things up the same way and getting a different result than this screenshot? i.imgur.com/TIjA8AS.png

Comment: Its working for you because you are using the test inside api.ai.  Yes this works fine but is not related to the web integration.  Once you are looking at this from an actual website, the random nature seems to jump up a level and selects just one random Text Response, not a random phrase from each Text Response.

Comment: There should be 2 messages in your response like: 
`"fulfillment": {
      "speech": "But my friends call me Dave",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "David"
        },
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "But my friends call me Dave"
        }
      ]
    }
`
Use messages to get multiple responses